# Does Dockerfile support inline comments?

Tags: dockerfile

I am not very familiar with the syntax of Dockerfile, please forgive me if this question is too simple.

1. comment a line

```
# Comment
```

2. inline comment

```
ENV foo prod # Comment
```

I've looked all over the docs and found no syntax for inline comments.
[Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

My question is, is the syntax of the second comment supported?
Thanks a lot!